# Java scanner object skipping lines?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So its been awhile since I've really written anything console based for java,

I have this method, below, which should be asking me for each line, right? Instead, I get one prompt, then three.. What did I do wrong herer?

```
        try {

        System.out.println("Please enter the product's LONG details: ");
        product.setLongDetails(sc.next()); //set products long details

        System.out.println("Please enter the product's SHORT details: ");
        product.setShortDetails(sc.next()); //set short details

        System.out.println("Please enter the product's UPC data: ");
        product.setUpc(sc.next()); //set upc

        System.out.println("Please enter the product's stock: ");
        product.setStock(sc.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Please enter the products price. ");
        System.out.println("This MUST be entered with no dollar sign.");
        product.setPrice(sc.nextBigDecimal());

        InventoryManager.addProduct(product); //add product to database

    }
```

My console is outputting like this:

```
Please enter the product's LONG details: 
Fireplace Cleaning Package
Please enter the product's SHORT details: 
Please enter the product's UPC data: 
Please enter the product's stock: 
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 3 minutes 5 seconds)
```

The scanner is initialized just inside the class declaration as:

```
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //class level scanner object for reuse.
```

If I call sc.nextLine() between each objects set method, it prompts correctly but gets the wrong information:

```
Please enter the product's SHORT details: 
Fire Poker
```

Displays the object as: 
Please enter your selection:
    `Fire`

Comment: How did you initialise the Scanner ``sc``?

Comment: Its declared as a class variable. I will add the initialization to the question, give me one second. Also, I just tested using sc.nextLine() between each call, and that might have fixed it but I am not completely sure without checking the data file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) states:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

That means that when you are entering a text with spaces (Like the "Fireplace Cleaning Package" in your example) it gets split into 3 different inputs, each returned by one call of `sc.next()`.

The solution is to adjust your delimeter pattern to newline:

```
sc.useDelimeter("\\r?\\n");
```

Comment: I would like to add, I was able to use the .useDelimeter("\\r?\\n") on the end of the initialization call after (System.In) so I wont have to reset the delimeter on each other method.

Comment: I'm glad it works for your purpose. In that case you might consider to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.next() takes the next complete token followed by a delimiter as described in the [doumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29). Since you type in three words (the delimiter here is a space), the first three

`sc.next()`

will read each of those words. I think what you are looking for instead is

`sc.nextLine()`